# TRN-Pytorch model - RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: github, pytorch, pre-trained-model, torchvision

I'm using [TRN-Pytorch model](https://github.com/metalbubble/TRN-pytorch) in colab and pytorch version is 0.4.1. While training the model I got a **RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)**

This is code for training

```
!python3 main.py something RGB \
                     --arch BNInception --num_segments 3 \
                     --consensus_type TRN --batch-size 2
```

and I got this Error

```
storing name: TRN_something_RGB_BNInception_TRN_segment3

    Initializing TSN with base model: BNInception.
    TSN Configurations:
        input_modality:     RGB
        num_segments:       3
        new_length:         1
        consensus_module:   TRN
        dropout_ratio:      0.8
        img_feature_dim:    256

/content/drive/My Drive/TRN-pytorch/models.py:87: UserWarning: nn.init.normal is now deprecated in favor of nn.init.normal_.
  normal(self.new_fc.weight, 0, std)
/content/drive/My Drive/TRN-pytorch/models.py:88: UserWarning: nn.init.constant is now deprecated in favor of nn.init.constant_.
  constant(self.new_fc.bias, 0)
video number:4
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:208: UserWarning: The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, please use transforms.Resize instead.
  "please use transforms.Resize instead.")
video number:1
group: first_conv_weight has 1 params, lr_mult: 1, decay_mult: 1
group: first_conv_bias has 1 params, lr_mult: 2, decay_mult: 0
group: normal_weight has 71 params, lr_mult: 1, decay_mult: 1
group: normal_bias has 71 params, lr_mult: 2, decay_mult: 0
group: BN scale/shift has 2 params, lr_mult: 1, decay_mult: 0
Freezing BatchNorm2D except the first one.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 324, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 128, in main
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, log_training)
  File "main.py", line 175, in train
    prec1, prec5 = accuracy(output.data, target, topk=(1,5))
  File "main.py", line 301, in accuracy
    batch_size = target.size(1)
RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

main.py file is [here](https://github.com/metalbubble/TRN-pytorch/blob/master/main.py)

Help me to solve this issue